# Can you add a Browsable API into an ASP.NET application?

Tags: asp.net, django, api, middleware, content-negotiation

**The Django web framework has a [Browsable API](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browsable-api/) and I would like to implement something similar in my ASP.NET (with ReactJS) application.** Essentially, suppose that there's an API endpoint called `api/test`; I would like to be able to navigate to `https://.../api/test` in a web browser and be presented with a web page (React component) that contains what `api/test` normally returns but in a better, human-readable format like Django does. But when accessed as an API, it returns the content without the surrounding HTML page. The simple controller would look like:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Produces("text/json")]
    public IList<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[]
        {
            "hello",
            "world"
        };
    }
}
```

It seems that something *similar* to [Content Negotiation](https://code-maze.com/content-negotiation-dotnet-core/) would work. So, I would either have to implement a custom formatter (which I'm not sure is the right approach) or make a middleware of my own.

Does this sort of thing already exist somehow? Any suggestions on how to implement it if it doesn't already exist? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tool like [Swagger](https://swagger.io/).

[Swashbuckle](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle/) is a Nuget package that adds Swagger to your application. It adds a couple of dependencies as well as a configuration file in your `App_Start` folder.

After adding the package, you can browse to `http://whateveryourappnameis.com/swagger` and see auto-generated documentation for your API. Here is a sample snapshot from an image service I recently created:

[image: snapshot]

As you can see, it even generates forms to submit requests so you can test your API!

It also supports additional configuration to customize your documentation.